# Routing of multiple views on the same templates in flask code

Tags: flask, undefined, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i need to point two views on a same template with different form names, i test with that code, but it not working :

```
@home.route('/blogs/Article/<int:id>/<string:url_path>', methods=['GET'])
def show_article(id, url_path):
    add_article = False
    blog = Article.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = ArticleForm(obj=blog)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        blog.titre = form.titre.data
        blog.url_path = form.url_path.data
        blog.writ_by = form.writ_by.data
        blog.body = form.body.data
        blog.date_creation = form.date_creation.data

        db.session.commit()        
        return redirect(url_for('home._blogs_'))    
    return render_template('home/blog.html', action="Edit", add_article=add_article, form=form, blog=blog, title="Edit blog")
```

###Second views

```
@home.route("/article/<int:id_article>/comment", methods=["POST"])
def comment_post(id_article):    
    article = Article.query.get_or_404(id_article)
    form_comment = AddCommentForm()
    if form_comment.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment(
            body_comment_article = form_comment.body_comment_article.data, 
            posted_name = form_comment.posted_name.data ,
            date_creation =  datetime.datetime.now(),        
            id_articles=article.id)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()        
        flash("Your comment has been added to the article", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("home.show_article", id=article.id , url_path=article.url_path))    
    return render_template("/home/blog.html", title="Comment Post", add_comment=add_comment, form_comment=form_comment, article=article)
```

the Code returns the following error:

```
UndefinedError: 'form_comment' is undefined
```

could you please help me, thank you

Comment: In your first route you are not passing form_comment to the template, hence the error. For a quick fix, wrap the for_comment variable in the template in an if statement {% if form_comment %}, and dont forget to put the {% endif %} in there as well.

Comment: this idea work good for me, but why Quick fix (is there any risk to use it), whele i passed form_comment in the first views like this (form_comment = AddCommentForm()) and in my templates i do the if statement for both form (form and form_comment)  and it work .
**{% if form %}... {%endif%}**
**{% if form_comment %}... {%endif%}**
it's possible combine btween the two views in one  !?

Comment: There is no real risk, but too many (nested?) if statements could cause other issues. Why bother yourself with this. My advice would be to create 2 different template, inheriting from the same base template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is.
in my first views i passed form_comment, and i add if statement in my template {%if for_comment%}... {%endif%}

```
@home.route('/blogs/Article/<int:id>/<string:url_path>', methods=['GET'])
def show_article(id, url_path):
    add_article = False
    blog = Article.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = ArticleForm(obj=blog)
    form_comment = AddCommentForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        blog.titre = form.titre.data
        blog.url_path = form.url_path.data
        blog.writ_by = form.writ_by.data
        blog.body = form.body.data
        blog.date_creation = form.date_creation.data

        db.session.commit()        
        return redirect(url_for('home._blogs_'))    
    return render_template('home/blog.html', action="Edit", add_article=add_article, form=form,form_comment=form_comment, blog=blog, title="Edit blog")
```